# How is possible Moro can defeat super saiyan blues but Majin Buu can fight him?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

Ok, so Moro can't absorb Majin Buu ki like he did with Goku and Vegeta. That still doesnt explain why at the begining of the fight when Vegeta power wasnt absorbed yet, he could fight at the level of him. Is Moro actually weak and his powerful magic attacks is energy borrowed from the Earth and magic and stuff? That still doesnt explain his resistance to hold a super saiyan blue. Does he have magic tricks for increasing his resistance with characters who dont have magic? Did Majin Buu grow stronger than a SSJ3? The question which sums it all up is,

How is possible Moro can defeat super saiyan blues but Majin Buu can fight him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Majin Buu  contains with in him the Grand Supreme Kai. The Grand Supreme Kai is, within his universe, second only in strength to the god of destruction (or possibly even stronger, remember Whis, a member of the same race, is said to be much stronger then Berus).It's also worth noting that the reason the supreme Kai lost is not because kid/pure Buu was stronger, he just absorbed him before he could react (he was actually holding his own very well). The resulting fat buu is only weaker then pure Buu because fat Buu was lazy and childish. 
We also don't know how strong Moro is in comparison to a fully powered super sayian blue: remember he stole their energy and weakened them. The fan base have suggested he is somewhere between super sayian 3 and god. SSJ3 Goku was only slightly stronger then Fat Buu and could not defeat him due to Buu's unlimited stamina. A powered up Fat Buu could easily contend with a SSJ3.5 Lv enemy.

So now we have the second strongest being in the universe stored within fat buu staring to awaken again from within fat Buu. This is why he was able to beat Moro: He's still the Supreme Grand Kai. He was the sole controller/guardian and overseer of universe 7.